# Solicitar números inteiros e contar pares e ímpares

Tags: python

Questão:

> "Faça um programa que solicite ao usuário 5 números inteiros e, ao 
>   final, informe a quantidade de números ímpares e pares lidos."

Estou com dificuldade nesta questão, eu realmente não sei nem começar ela, até então tenho:

```
for n1 in range(5):
    n1 = input("Digite um numero:")
```

Mas acredito que não deve ser assim que se começa ela.
(Lembrando que uso o Python no PyCharm)

Comment: O que você já conseguiu fazer?

Comment: Nesse caso, quais partes você **já sabe** fazer?

Comment: Ola @Mel, Bem vinda ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour] =D, agora sobre sua pergunta, ela será mais bem recebida pela comunidade se você adicionar mais informações como: **Estou com duvida nessa parte ...**, **Consegui fazer isso até agora ...**. Sua pergunta atualmente esta pedindo para alguém fazer para você o exercício.  [ask]

Comment: `print('Contagem de pares e ímpares, respectivamente:', *map(sum, zip(*((int(n) % 2 == 0, int(n) % 2 != 0) for n in input('Informe 5 números separados por espaço: ').split()))))`

Comment: Tem um link de excluir na pergunta, se quiser. Mas editei o conteúdo e estou reabrindo, quem sabe agora você não consegue uma resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Você estava no caminho certo.

Vamos começar criando duas variáveis pra contar quantos números pares e ímpares são informados.

```
contador_pares = 0
contador_impares = 0
```

Depois fazemos o laço pedindo os números pro usuário, seguindo a abordagem que você tinha iniciado na sua tentativa.

```
for i in range(5):
    entrada = input('Digite um numero: ')

    numero = int(entrada)

    if numero % 2 == 0:
        contador_pares += 1
    else:
        contador_impares += 1
```

Note que dentro do laço é preciso converter a entrada pra `int`, pois o retorno da função `input` é uma string, e nós precisamos de um número. Além disso, pra testar se um número é par, fazemos o módulo dele por 2. Se o módulo for 0 significa que ele é divisível por 2 e, portanto, é par.

Depois do laço, basta exibir os resultados.

```
print('Quantidade pares:', contador_pares)
print('Quantidade impares:', contador_impares)
```

Segue o código completo.

```
contador_pares = 0
contador_impares = 0

for i in range(5):
    entrada = input('Digite um numero: ')

    numero = int(entrada)

    if numero % 2 == 0:
        contador_pares += 1
    else:
        contador_impares += 1

print('Quantidade pares:', contador_pares)
print('Quantidade impares:', contador_impares)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa de implementar um programa que receba `5` números `inteiros` e, em seguida, `exiba` a quantidade de valores `pares` e `ímpares` que foram digitados. Pois bem, o algoritmo correto se encontra logo abaixo.

```
# Iniciando as variáveis contadoras:
numeros_pares = numeros_impares = 0
for c in range(1, 6):
    # Capturando e tratando os valores digitados:
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(f'Digite o {c}º número: '))
            break
        except:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

    # Verificando se cada número digitado é par ou ímpar:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        # Contando os números pares:
        numeros_pares += 1
    else:
        # Contando os números ímpares:
        numeros_impares += 1

# Imprimindo a quantidade de números pares e ímpares:
print(f'\033[32mA quantidade de números pares é: {numeros_pares}')
print(f'A quantidade de números ímpares é: {numeros_impares}\033[m')
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/ymvnebne-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que este programa possui um `tratamento` de erros e exceções. Pois, ele só permite números `inteiros`.

Em seguida, ele conta os números `pares` e `ímpares` para posteriormente exibir suas quantidades.